# Need to display output in json and it to other server say "www.hashserver.com" but using angular

Tags: php, angularjs, json, http-headers, http-post

This is the code.
I don't know what is wrong with the code its not working. I guess there is some problem with header defined but syntax is correct. there is no-db(database)

```
     <script>
 angular.module('submitExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.text = '';
    $scope.submit = function() {
      if ($scope.text) {
        $scope.list.push(this.text);
        $scope.text = '';
        $http.post("www.sendtohashserver.com/db",method: "POST", {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} $scope.list).success(function(data, status) {
      console.log(data);
        })
      }
    };
  }]);
</script>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list| json}}</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: "It is not working": Please define what "it is not working" mean? Do you get an error message? Nothing's happening or what?

Comment: 1)Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
angular.js:38 Uncaught

2) Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=submitExample&p1=Er…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)

Comment: but i have checked all the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$http` service like this:

```
$http.post("www.sendtohashserver.com/db", $scope.list, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
}).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

JSFiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/361/).

Documentation for `$http` states this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods).

> Shortcut methods are also available. All shortcut methods require passing in the URL, and request data must be passed in for POST/PUT requests. An optional config can be passed as the last argument.
>
> `$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`
> `$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Comment: Getting this error on submitting value

error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.....gpsdb/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'eaxmple.com'; is therefore not allowed access

Comment: This will be because the URL you are trying to post to is in a different domain than where your page is hosted. There is a mechanism called CORS that can be used to control what HTTP verbs can be used from which domain. This has to be enabled on the server side though, so if you don't control the server, you're out of luck.

Comment: Server accepts json and my output is not in json is it because of that server is not accepting

Comment: I don't think I can tell you more than just to read about CORS and understand it. You can't just willy-nilly send XMLHttpRequests all around the world. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct: the second argument to $http.post has wrong syntax; the brackets are unbalanced; *$scope.list* appears in an invalid position. 
Your code, as you provided it, will raise JavaScript errors.

Also it is not intended to pass the http *method* when you are calling *$http.post*, which has the method already in its name.

It helps to indent your code properly to spot some of these problems. Here is what you could try:

```
$http.post(
    "www.sendtohashserver.com/db",
    $scope.list,
    {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } 
).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

If the server you call requests the data to be JSON string formatted, then call `JSON.stringify`:

```
$http.post(
    "www.sendtohashserver.com/db",
    JSON.stringify($scope.list),
    {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    } 
).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

However, your request is a [cross-origin request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and will be rejected if the called service has not white-listed your domain.

Comment: error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.....gpsdb/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://eaxmple.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Unrelated to the syntax error you had. Look into CORS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: The error message says it all. The called website does not allow requests from other domains, like yours.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the website you call wants you to send JSON? You have a reference to the documentation of that service?